# Why not always use rsync?

Tags: linux, rsync, cp

I wanted to ask is there any reason not to use `rsync` for everything and abandon `cp`?
I wasn't aware of `rsync` and now I don't know why `cp` is ever needed.

Comment: `rsync` ins't available everywhere, `cp` is.

Comment: @Mat:It is not?You mean it is not part of the default installation?

Comment: Which installation? Linux? Which one? Unix? ditto. BSD? You never know what comes by default.

Comment: There really ins't a "default installation" for Linux. Every distro has its set of core packages and a host of variations in those. Also when you need to work on a lot of systems, using the tools available everywhere makes things simpler.

Comment: @Mat:Point taken..

Comment: @Mat : There is a default (or core) installation in so far as linux distros comply, via the base GNU userland, with POSIX, which requires (and defines the functioning of) `cp` but not `rsync`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/contents.htm

Comment: Agree with @Mat, i.e.: rsync is not available in BusyBox based systems

Comment: I'm pretty sure Debian GNU/Linux installs rsync by default. It is, however, *not* available in the installation and rescue environment. (I used that early today to transfer the contents of my root partition from one disk to another. Used the 7.1.0 amd64 install DVD.)

Comment: Isn't it a bit like using a chainsaw to cut a matchstick sometimes?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Strictly speaking yes, you can always use `rsync`. From `man rsync` (emphasis mine):

> Rsync  is  a  fast and extraordinarily versatile file    copying
>   tool.  It can copy locally,  to/from  another    host over any remote
>   shell, or to/from a remote rsync    daemon.  It offers a large  number
>   of  options  that    control  every aspect of its behavior and permit
>   very    flexible specification of the  set  of  files  to  be
>   copied.   It  is  famous for its delta-transfer algo‐    rithm, which
>   reduces the amount of data sent over the    network  by  sending only
>   the differences between the    source files and the existing files in 
>   the  destina‐    tion.  **Rsync is widely used for backups and mirroring
>   and as an improved copy command for everyday use.**

Now, sometimes it is just not worth typing those few extra characters just to use a tank to kill a fly. Also, `rsync` is often not installed by default so `cp` is nice to have.

Comment: You mean not available as part of the default installation but a separate download?

Comment: @Jim yes, sometimes you need to install `rsync` yourself depending on the system you find yourself on. If you don't have `root` access that can be hard. `cp` is POSIX and will _always_ be there.

Comment: `cp` is part of the [GNU coreutils](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_core_utilities) so it is always installed on every Linux system while `rsync` is not.

Comment: `sometimes it is just not worth typing those few extra characters` - I've aliased `pcp` (for "progress copy") for that  ;)

Answer (score 19):

Rsync can be slower than `cp` in some situations. For example when the destination exists and rsync ends up doing some expensive comparisons for each block, does not find equal blocks and copies the complete source file anyways.

Also when destination files don't exist, rsync does not provide any advantage above cp.

Comment: Underneath, rsync's copy methodology is significantly slower. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374071/why-does-the-rsync-reader-perform-two-writes-per-4k-of-data . An strace of cp shows (as of this writing), a simple 32KB read/32 KB write sequence of operations. Rsync, meanwhile, does a read/4092-byte + 4-byte write to socket/read from socket/250KB write to file. I am doing an rsync of 36T of mixed size files at 130MB/s throughput. I can triple that with cp -a. rsync wins, as you say when you want to "make 'that' look like 'this'" on directories that are already similar.

Answer (score 7):

I think `rsync` doesn't handle copying sparse file in a straightforward manner. `cp` by default handles that very well.

Comment: It does with the `-S` flag.

Comment: @terdon, Oh well, please refer to this article: http://www.barricane.com/rsync-vm-sparse-inplace-kvm-vmware.

Comment: Ah, thanks, you should add that to your answer. I just quickly searched the man page for `sparse`.

Answer (score 4):

Because this `cp` flag is lacking in rsync:

```
-i, --interactive
       prompt before overwrite (overrides a previous -n option)
```

Comment: No, although there is `-n` (dry run) on rsync, which can be kind of a substitute to that feature.